# If $|\int f_n-\int f |\to 0 \Rightarrow\int |f_n - f| \to 0$.?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $|\int f_n -\int f| \to 0 \Leftrightarrow  |\int (f_n-f) |\to 0$ where  $f_n$ and $f$  have the hypothesis of dominated convergence theorem

It is true that:

If $|\int f_n-\int f |\to 0 \Rightarrow\int |f_n - f| \to 0$.?

Comment: You seem to have assumed your conclusion in the statement of your question.

Comment: No, the first part is just linearity of the integral. The absolute value remains on the outside.

Comment: I was wrong to question sorry

Answer (score 3):

This statement is false. For example, let $f = 0$ and $f_n = \text{id} \cdot \chi_{[-1, 1]}$, the identity function on $[-1, 1]$. Then $\int f_n - f = 0$ so $|\int f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$ but $\int |f_n-f| = 1$. The opposite implication is true by Clement C's post.

Answer (score 1):

If both integrals are well-defined (both $f$ and $g$ are integrable),
$$\left\lvert \int (g-f) \right\rvert \leq\int \lvert g-f \rvert$$
by the triangle inequality.

---

Edit: to answer the (new) question: no, the other implication is false. Look at the example given above by Solomonoff: you need to assume some convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ to hope that such implication holds.

Edit 2: also, to clarify: what do you mean by "Comply with the hypothesis of dominated convergence theorem"?

Comment: You'd need the opposite inequality to prove the above result.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret well, of course -- the question has changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the question as it is currently stated since $\int \left|f_n - f\right| \to 0$ is a consequence of the hypotheses of the dominated convergence theorem.

I think the OP's question is this:

---

Assume $f_n$ and $f$  satisfy most of the hypotheses of the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), i.e. $|f_n|\leq|g|$ for some integrable function $g$ and all $f_n$ are measureable, but that $f_n$ doesn't converge to $f$ pointwise.

If $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise, assuming the rest of the hypotheses of the dominated convergence theorem hold, we get that 
$$\int \left|f_n - f\right| \to 0$$
which also implies that
$$ \left|\int f_n -\int f\right| \to 0.$$

***The question:***

If we do not assume $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise, but instead assume that 
$$\left|\int f_n-\int f \right|\to 0,$$
is it true that
$$\int \left|f_n - f\right| \to 0?$$

---

In general $\left|\int f_n-\int f \right|\to 0$ does not tell you much about the functions except that the have the same area underneath them in the limit. As noted by "@Salomonoff's Secret", $f_n(x)=x$ on $[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ have the same integral, but $\int \left|f_n - f\right|=1$.